# Laravel 5.4 Model Accessor Methods not working

Tags: php, accessor, laravel-5.4

i'm trying make an accessor, for post permalink. If i understand correctly it will change my premalink when i create new entry, but it doesn't

```
<?php

class Story extends Model
{
use UuidTrait;
public $incrementing = false;
protected $table     = 'stories';
protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'text', 'tags', 'user_id', 'permalink',
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\User', 'user_id');
}
/**
 * Set the permalink.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return void
 */
public function sePermalinkAttribute($value)
{
    if(empty($value)){
     $value = $this->attributes['title'];
    }
    $this->attributes['permalink'] = str_slug($value);
}
}
```

But i get NULL when save my model. Why does accessor not working?
`$user->stories()->create($data['data']);`

Comment: se**t**PermalinkAttribute() letter missing.

Comment: oh, thanks i'm blind